# HAProxy balancing on header while hiding it from the backend

Tags: haproxy, sticky-sessions

I'm trying to set up HAProxy such that it picks a backend based on a header value. But I also want to hide that header from backends.

My config:

```
defaults
  mode http
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 5s
  timeout server 5s 

listen lb
  bind *:1234
  balance hdr(Proxy-Authorization)
  # http-request del-header Proxy-Authorization
  server srv1 192.0.2.1:8080
  server srv2 192.0.2.2:8080
  server srv3 192.0.2.3:8080
```

With this config `Proxy-Authorization` is passed down to backends, which I wanted to avoid. If I uncomment `http-request del-header Proxy-Authorization` it disappears, but also `balance hdr(Proxy-Authorization)` can no longer see it and starts just doing round-robin.

Is it possible to balance based on a header value and hide it from the backend at the same time?

Comment: `http-request` is processed very early, while `balance` is very late... but I suspect there are other complications here -- unsure, but HAProxy may redistribute requests if one backend goes down, even if the requests wouldn't have gone to the affected backend.  I think.  You might look at storing the header value in a variable, then using that variable in conjunction with a stick table.  I think that could be the more "proper" solution, since your objective seems like it might be related to stickiness rather than balancing.

Comment: Have you tried `reqdel ^Proxy-Authorization:` in the backend definitions?

Comment: @wurtel Yes I tried that, effect is the same as `http-request del-header`: fallback to round-robin.